# How should I write this higher order function where the parameter func needs an implicit view?

Tags: scala, implicit

I have a function that makes use of an implicit view to a Seq[A], you can see it makes use of the head method and preserves types:-

```
scala> def needSeq[A, C <% Seq[A]](col: C) = { (col.head , col) }
needSeq: [A, C](col: C)(implicit evidence$1: C => Seq[A])(A, C)

scala> needSeq(List(1,2,3))
res0: (Int, List[Int]) = (1,List(1, 2, 3))

scala> needSeq(List("a","b"))
res1: (java.lang.String, List[java.lang.String]) = (a,List(a, b))

scala> needSeq(Array("a","b"))
res2: (java.lang.String, Array[java.lang.String]) = (a,Array(a, b))
```

I want to write a function that takes functions like needSeq and applies them to arguments

```
scala> def useFunc[A, C <% Seq[A], R](col: C)(f: C => R) = { f(col) }
useFunc: [A, C, R](col: C)(f: C => R)(implicit evidence$1: C => Seq[A])R
```

The problem is because only one type (C) is provided in the parameter list there is no implicit view from C => Seq[A] available

```
scala> useFunc(List(1,2,3))(needSeq)
<console>:10: error: No implicit view available from C => Seq[A].
              useFunc(List(1,2,3))(needSeq)
                                   ^
```

How should I write useFunc?

Comment: Using `useFunc(List(1,2,3))(x => needSeq(x))` instead of `useFunc(List(1,2,3))(needSeq)`

Comment: Thanks @Eastsun that works :-) ,and of course `useFunc(List(1,2,3))(needSeq(_))` works too... could you please explain why the compiler can now find the implicit view? Is it because the evaluation is somehow delayed more until useFunc makes use of the 'f' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that solution from @Eastsun

```
 useFunc(List(1,2,3))(x => needSeq(x))
```

works because the **C** from

```
def useFunc[A, C <% Seq[A], R](col: C)(f: C => R)
```

is now represented by the **x** and kind of *connects* the type of the List with the type of parameter that the needSeq takes

or one could say that the two lines above better resemble each other that way :

```
 def useFunc[A, C <% Seq[A], R]  (col: C)   (f: C => R)
     useFunc                  (List(1,2,3)) (x => needSeq(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in definition `needSeq`..
if you can try to  refactor it to..

```
def needSeq[A](col : Seq[A]) = (col.head , col)
```

then both of these cases works..

```
useFunc(List(1,2,3))(needSeq) //> res1: (Int, Seq[Int]) = (1,List(1, 2, 3))

useFunc(List(1,2,3))(x => needSeq(x)) //> res2: (Int, Seq[Int]) = (1,List(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: Hi Thanks @Shrey, the trouble is that that messes up the use case with Array ,see above example,  which now gives returns a runtime type of WrappedArray, ie it looses some type information... so I'm still looking for the solution :-/

Comment: in fact it loosses type info in the List use case too, see how it returns (Int, Seq[Int]) in stead of (Int, List(1,2,3)) ?